# How to change the text color of the button theme in Flutter

Tags: button, text, colors, flutter, themes

If I add a theme to my app like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff393e46),
        primaryColorDark: Color(0xff222831),
        accentColor: Color(0xff00adb5),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffeeeeee),
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          buttonColor: Color(0xff00adb5),
        )
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How do I change the text color for the button theme?

Answer (score 54):

If you use `ButtonTextTheme.primary` Flutter will automatically select the right color for you.

For example, if you make the `buttonColor` dark like this

```
  ThemeData(
    . . . 
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      buttonColor: Colors.deepPurple,     //  <-- dark color
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary, //  <-- this auto selects the right color
    )
  ),
```

[image]

The text is automatically light. And if you make the `buttonColor` light, then the text is dark.

```
  ThemeData(
    . . . 
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      buttonColor: Colors.yellow,         //  <-- light color
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary, //  <-- dark text for light background
    )
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: This works great for many colors, but some it doesn't, or in some cases we want a different color than black and white... how to define it then?

Comment: @mFeinstein, you can use `colorScheme` as Andrey Gordeev shows.

Comment: Great! Thanks! PS: Could you take a look on my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294421/how-to-make-a-widget-to-be-as-small-as-it-can-wrap-content-in-android

Comment: How to apply primary color to buttonColor property rather than hardcoding it? Anyway?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal, you can get the primary color from the theme like this: `Theme.of(context).primaryColor`.

Comment: how to do it for elevated button theme data. elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Color(0xfff52e6b),
          ),
        ),

Answer (score 31):

I believe the more updated answer is mainly found here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black,), //button color
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0xffffffff),), //text (and icon)
  ),
),
```

Depending on the button change...

```
elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData()
outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData()
textButtonTheme: textButtonThemeData()
```

Comment: Important, theme must be build with `ThemeData.from(colorScheme: ColorScheme.light())`

Answer (score 29):

Suragch's answer is correct, but sometimes we want to set a completely custom color as button text color. It is achievable by providing a custom `colorScheme` with `secondary` color set:

```dart
buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
  buttonColor: Color(0xffff914d), // Background color (orange in my case).
  textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
  colorScheme:
    Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(secondary: Colors.white), // Text color
),
```

[image: Flutter button change to custom text color]

Comment: this works well, what if I don't want to pass in context for whatever reasons

Comment: dear i am still getting blue button color. Thanks

Comment: some of the properties about themeData are now deprecated, and no longer work! the new version of flutter don't allow that code to work properly!

Answer (score 12):

Related: As I stumbled upon this when looking specifically for `TextButton` color, setting the MaterialApp theme solved that:

```
theme: ThemeData(
      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

found on https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-textbutton-widget-examples

Answer (score 11):

#### Update (New buttons):

**Enabled state:**

[image]

**Disabled state:**

[image]

`ButtonTheme` won't work for new buttons like `ElevatedButton`. For that you should set `elevatedButtonTheme`.

- #### Less customizations:

  ```dart
  MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red, // Button color
          foregroundColor: Colors.white, // Text color
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```
- #### More customizations:

  ```dart
  MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((s) {
            if (s.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) return Colors.brown; // Disabled button color
            return Colors.red; // Enabled button color
          }),
          foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((s) {
            if (s.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) return Colors.white30; // Disabled text color
            return Colors.white; // Enabled text color
          }),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
  ```

Similarly, you can do this for `OutlinedButton` and `TextButton` by replacing `ElevatedButton` and its properties.

Comment: You can use `disabledBackgroundColor` & `disabledForegroundColor` properties instead of adding if else.

Answer (score 4):

Andrey Gordeev's answer works. However I was curious what's going on so do a check on it as lacking a bit of explanation. Basically you **need** to set the `textTheme` to `accent` in order to use the `colorScheme` to set the button color. You can also override the button color using the primary in the `colorScheme`.

From the source code

```
The colors for new button classes can be defined exclusively in termsof [colorScheme].  
When it's possible, the existing buttons will (continue to) gradually migrate to it.
```

```dart
buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
    textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
    colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
          primary: Colors.orange,
          // secondary will be the textColor, when the textTheme is set to accent
          secondary: Colors.white,
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to set it in the app theme, so it will be applied everywhere:

*src/theme/style.dart*

```dart
final appTheme = () => ThemeData(
      accentColor: Colors.white,
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
        buttonColor: Colors.orange,
        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent,
      ),
    );
```

Then use it in your *src/app.dart* as `theme: appTheme(),`

Try it :

```dart
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () => print('pressed'),
  child: Text('Press me'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The way I did it. I wanted specific color for text and background only for this button.

```
            ElevatedButton(
                  style: const ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor:
                        MaterialStatePropertyAll<Color>(Colors.white),
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStatePropertyAll<Color>(Colors.green),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    appState.toggleFavorite();
                  },
                  child: Text('Fav'),
                )
```