# How to make a Widget to be as small as it can (wrap_content in Android)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a rendering issue with render tree similar to `Column`>`PageView`>`Column`, where the last `Column` is inside a page of the `PageView`.

The `PageView` isn't being rendered correctly, so I get an exception (`Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.`) as the framework can't calculate its sizes, I can fix it by wrapping it into a `Flexible` or an `Expanded`, but I don't want the `PageView` to take the whole screen, I want it to be as small as possible and on the center on the screen.

Here's a representation of my problem:

```
// This code throws an exception:

class Widget_1_Has_Problem extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.done,size: 112),
          SizedBox(height: 32),
          PageView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: pageController,
            children: <Widget>[
            // Many widgets go here, I am just simplifying with a Column.
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT'),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text('TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what I wanted to achieve (I removed the `PageView` in order to show it):

[image: Desired UI]

```
class Widget_2_No_PageView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.done,size: 112),
          SizedBox(height: 32),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT'),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              Text('TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I can fix it, but it's not perfect, I will show later:

[image: Solution with Flexible/Expanded]

```
class Widget_3_With_Flex_Not_Perfect_Solution extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(flex: 2,),
          Icon(Icons.done,size: 112),
          SizedBox(height: 32),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: PageView(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: pageController,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT'),
                    SizedBox(height: 16),
                    Text('TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2'),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(flex: 2,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This solution isn't perfect because `Spacer` and `Flexible` or `Expanded` always try to maintain it's proportionality of the `flex` weight, which means that for smaller displays the `Spacer` won't vanish, it will remain there, whereas the first and desired image won't have such a void space. As we can see in the below image, the Spacer is always there. Also I have to calculate the `flex` factor for every change in this design, whereas in my first code example the widget will size itself to the center of the screen automatically.

[image: Spacer into the UI]

How can I instruct `PageView` then to be as small as it can be, instead of expand as much as it wants, as that's the only solution I can find online?

Comment: tried `IntrinsicHeight`?

Comment: No, I didn't, as far as I understood, `IntrinsicHeight` made all the widgets inside a `Row` the same size

Comment: the docs say: *"A widget that sizes its child to the child's intrinsic height.

This class is useful, for example, when unlimited height is available and you would like a child that would otherwise attempt to expand infinitely to instead size itself to a more reasonable height."*

Comment: Ohh that sounds promising, I knew from examples only. The naming should be more descriptive, "intrinsic" is very technical and most foreigners won't even know what it means

Comment: @pskink I just tried `IntrinsicHeight` and it doesn't work...did it work for you?

Comment: i did not try, i just mentioned  that such widget exists

Comment: Well it was a good tip, thanks anyway

Comment: Will all the children of `PageView` be of the same height?

Comment: No, each of them is different

Comment: Ok. So do you expect the `PageView` widget to have the height of the page with the largest height? Or do you expect it to change height depending on which page is displayed?

Comment: I think I expect it to change height... But it won't hurt to know how to make it as tall as the tallest page as well as a side option to be documented as well.

Comment: Do you need PageView? Your example uses NeverScrollableScrollPhysics which disables the most interesting part. Maybe AnimatedSwitcher would do the job.

Comment: I could use `AnimatedSwitcher` but it would be more complicated, as I will have to set the paging transition and keep a list of the widgets and their order separately. `PageView` gives me all of it and a `PageViewController` which simplify it a lot and provides lots of interesting extra functionalities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PageView` uses `SliverFillViewport` to wrap around given `children`.

This `SliverFillViewport` doesn't care about how small the `children` are. It only cares how much space it can occupy from its parent. So the `Flex` and `Align` widget are useless.

Currently with `PageView`, it most likely not possible unless we do some calculation and use `SizedBox` or `ConstrainedBox`.

I also found this [discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11273)

Answer (score 4):

This can be done, but not with PageView. I had to use SingleChildScrollView with a Row. The reason for that is: if you want to size your PageView properly, you need to build and layout every child it has. PageView does not do that, but Row does, you can even decide how smaller elements should be positioned. PageController also works if you properly set widths of children in the row.

Note that this will only work nicely if you have small amount of pages.

```
class SizingPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollPhysics physics;
  final PageController controller;
  final List<Widget> children;

  const SizingPageView({Key key, this.physics, this.controller, this.children})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget transform(Widget input) {
      return SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: input,
      );
    }

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: physics ?? PageScrollPhysics(),
      controller: controller,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: children.map(transform).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Solution extends StatelessWidget {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(
            flex: 2,
          ),
          Icon(Icons.done, size: 112),
          SizedBox(height: 32),
          Text('BEFORE SCROLL'),
          SizingPageView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: pageController,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT'),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text('TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2'),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT'),
                ],
              ),
              Text('Third'),
            ],
          ),
          Text('AFTER SCROLL'),
          Spacer(
            flex: 2,
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Next'),
            onPressed: () {
              var next = pageController.page.round() + 1;
              if (next >= 3) {
                next = 0;
              }
              pageController.animateToPage(
                next,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut,
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @mFeinstein sorry, a typo. I meant that it will only work for small amount of pages, because Flutter needs to layout every one of them to calculate the final size.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for items inside of the PageView to set the size of PageView itself. This is not going to work with the standard class. If you look at its source, you'll find that uses Viewport inside Scrollable. Viewport grabs maximum size and ignores the size of the children (Slivers). You'll need to use a different approach or maybe create a custom PageView, perhaps one that uses ShrinkWrappingViewport.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ShrinkWrappingViewport-class.html

Comment: The `Scrollable` widget is common every page in page view. We cann't make it smaller for one page, then make it bigger for the next page.

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping `PageView` inside `SizedBox`, we can get rid of the exception you are getting. (`Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.`).

```
SizedBox(height: 32, child:
          PageView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: pageController,
            children: <Widget>[
            // Many widgets go here, I am just simplifying with a Column.
              Column(
              ...
```

But that will give you a `bottom overflow exception` of 16 pixels since you have another `SizedBox` with fixed height inside `Column` in `PageView`.

[image: ![enter image description here]

In order to resolve this issue, let's just for time being replace top `SizedBox` with `Container` and add `color` property to it to see how much space and height is available to us.

[image]

So, instead of hardcoding the sizedbox height to 32, we can make use of `MediaQuery` to calculate height for us.

If you print height of the top `SizedBox`, it will come out to be 597

`SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,`

I for demo, divided the `height` with 5 to get 119.4 height of the `SizedBox` widget that contains `PageView`, which resolves the renderflow exception as well as maintains pageview's location at center of the screen.

[image]

If we again use `Container` to see now how much space and height is available to us, it will look like:

[image]

So with this approach, you will not be required to use `Expanded` or `Flexible` widgets as you mentioned and won't need to change much of your code.

The working code is as below:

```
h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5;  
    print(h);  // 119.4
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.done,size: 112),
          SizedBox(height: h, child:
          PageView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: pageController,
            children: <Widget>[
            // Many widgets go here, I am just simplifying with a Column.
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT'),
                  SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Text('TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2'),   
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
         ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

You might need to adjust height per your need, but I hope this resolves your issue and answers your question.

Comment: This is not the kind of answer I am looking for, I want something automatic, not something that I have to be calculating and if I add a new widget I have to change the numbers. This whole `MediaQuery` calculation should be done by the Framework with Layout Widgets, not by myself. This is more a workaround than a solution and I am looking for the "correct way to achieve this", not "how to make it work".

Answer (score -1):

You can simply wrap your widget with `Flexible` widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html

Comment: Read the post, that's the first thing I did.

Comment: Haha..Sorry i forgot.will get you the perfect answer soon