# Why isn't text color of Flutter button automatically adjusted based on the background color?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

So, it looks like default text color for `ElevatedButton` is white while default text color for (deprecated) `RaisedButton` is black.

I would like the text color to be automatically modified based on the background color (light color -> black, dark color -> white).

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56194169/2291710) I used a custom `ButtonThemeData` but this doesn't apply to `ElevatedButton`. I know there exist [`ElevatedButtonTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButtonTheme-class.html) and [`ElevatedButtonThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButtonThemeData-class.html) but I'm a bit lost about how to override them properly.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary)),
      home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Buttons())),
    );
  }
}

class Buttons extends StatefulWidget {
  const Buttons({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ButtonsState createState() => _ButtonsState();
}

class _ButtonsState extends State<Buttons> {
  var color = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("RaisedButton (set black)"),
          color: color,
          onPressed: () => setState(() => color = Colors.black),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("ElevatedButton (set white)"),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: color),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => color = Colors.white),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demonstration switching background color]

Please, how can I get the same result for my `ElevatedButton`, without having to specify the text color in `TextButton.styleFrom()`?

For what it's worth, I noticed this change while switching from Flutter 2.0.6 to 2.2.3.